# Building dynamic URL using 'a href'

Tags: jquery, html, spring, dynamic-url

I am using spring-3.2 version.

```
@RequestMapping("/company={companyId}/branch={branchId}/employee={employeeId}/info")
```

The requestmapping is used to map a URL, so in this case when ever a URL is called using

```
<a href="company=1/branch=1/employee=1/info" > employee info </a>
```

the method is called in the controller with the exact @RequestMapping annotation, now I want to create the "a href" tag dynamically and want to create companyId,branchId,or employeeId  dynamically.

Comment: And you want to somehow do this with jQuery ?

Comment: I dont know what to do to achieve it, please suggest me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could of course build the string pointing to the respective URL dynamically.

A first option would be using a javascript function. However, even this function has to take the IDs from somewhere. In my example, I suppose that there are javascript variables which already contain the right IDs.

```
function createDynamicURL()
{
    //The variable to be returned
    var URL;

    //The variables containing the respective IDs
    var companyID=...
    var branchID=...
    var employeeID=...

    //Forming the variable to return    
    URL+="company=";
    URL+=companyID;
    URL+="/branch=";
    URL+=branchID;
    URL+="/employee=";
    URL+=employeeID;
    URL+="/info";

    return URL;
}
```

Then your html would be like:

```
<a href="javascript:window.location=createDynamicURL();" > employee info </a>
```

Another, more elegant solution would be to use the onClick event:

```
<a href="#" onclick="RedirectURL();return false;" > employee info </a>
```

with the function

```
function RedirectURL()
{
    window.location= createDynamicURL();
}
```

Hope I helped!

Comment: my "javascript:createDynamicURL();" is not getting called.,

Comment: No I haven't checked it yet . I think javascript function is not getting called  from inside the html tag.

Comment: You could use the F12 button on Chrome or Mozilla and debug javascript using breakpoints. There you will see if anything goes wrong...

Comment: This is mostly correct. I just edited it to add window.location= to the top answer. It didn't work without it. Otherwise this was a great suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: Is it also possible to remove words from the URL? When trying this I get 'undefined' in my URL. Please take a look at my question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62367518/13290801

Answer (score 0):

We can use following example:

```
<a id="addBtn" href="#" onclick="get_dynamic_url();">Google</a></p>

<script>
function get_dynamic_url() {
    url = "Your dynamic url value";
    $("#addBtn").attr("href", url);
    return true;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is 2022. Use [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) or [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL_API) to build url.

Docs have everything you need.