# Passing dynamic javascript variable as url in template

Tags: javascript, django, function, url, dynamic-url

I am trying to create a dynamic url in javascript to pass to my html template.

In my js, I've got:

```
// dynamic url to edit flashcard
function createDynamicURL()
{
    //The variable to be returned
    var URL;

    //The variables containing the respective IDs
    var cardID= cards.cards[current_card].id   //this is defined earlier

    //Forming the variable to return
    URL-="study/[1-9][0-9]/";
    URL+="card-edit/";
    URL+=cardID;

    return URL;
}
```

And in my template I have:

```
<a id="edit-button" class="btn btn-default btn-warning" href="javascript:window.location=createDynamicURL();"  >Edit</a>
```

My urls.py:

```
app_name = 'flash'

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^study/(?P<deck_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.study, name='study'),
    re_path(r'^study/(?P<deck_id>[0-9]+)/get_cards/$', views.get_cards, name='get-cards'),
    path("decks/",views.DeckList.as_view(),name="deck-list"),
    path("decks/<int:pk>/",views.DeckDetail.as_view(),name="deck-detail"),
    path("cards/<int:pk>/", views.CardList.as_view(), name="flash-list"),
    path("card-edit/<int:pk>/",views.CardEdit.as_view(),name="flash-edit"),
    path("card-detail/<int:pk>/",views.CardDetail.as_view(),name="flash-detail"),
    path("edit/<int:pk>/",views.DeckUpdate.as_view(),name="edit"),
    path("",views.home,name="home"),

]
```

The url I get when I click: 
http://127.0.0.1:8000/%2Fflash/study/33/NaNcard-edit/51

The the correct url would have been: 
http://127.0.0.1:8000/%2Fflash/card-edit/51/

So at least it is giving me the correct id. But why is it giving me NaN, and how do I get rid of the study/33? Note the 33 will not always be 33, and I don't have access to that id here, so I want it to be just any 2-digit number.

I don't have a lot of experience with javascript, so sorry for the basic question. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Study views:

```
@login_required
@ensure_csrf_cookie
def study(request, deck_id):
    """
    Study cards page (JS driven)
    """
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'flash/study.html')


@login_required
@csrf_exempt
def get_cards(request, deck_id):
    """
    Get cards to study (ajax)
    """

    if request.method == 'GET':
        cards = Flashcard.objects.filter(owner=request.user, deck=deck_id,
                                         next_due_date__lte=timezone.now())
        count = len(cards)
        data = {'count': count, 'cards': []}

        num = count if count < CARD_LIMIT else CARD_LIMIT
        if num:
            # generate list of random indexes
            idx = random.sample(range(count), num)
            for i in idx:
                card = cards[i]
                question = '<p>'+'</p><p>'.join(card.question.split('\r\n'))+'</p>'
                answer = '<p>'+'</p><p>'.join(card.answer.split('\r\n'))+'</p>'
                data['cards'].append({'id': card.pk, 'question': question,
                                     'answer': answer})

        return JsonResponse(data)
    else:
        data = json.loads(str(request.body, 'utf-8'))
        for res in data:
            card = Flashcard.objects.get(owner=request.user, pk=res['id'])
            card.save(rating=res['result'])

        return JsonResponse({'status': 'OK'})
```

Comment: You're initializing an empty string URL then calling "URL-="study/[1-9][0-9]/";", which doesn't make sense since URL is empty at that point, so that's probably what is causing the NaN part of the string. What url do you get if you comment that line?

Comment: @ketcham If I remove "URL-="study/[1-9][0-9]/";", I get: http://127.0.0.1:8000//flash/study/33/undefinedcard-edit/51

Comment: It worked when I put `URL = "/flash"` in the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the card object in your template, Try this :

```
<a id="edit-button" class="btn btn-default btn-warning" href="{% url 'flash-edit' card.id %}"  >Edit</a>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to the card object in my template

Comment: in your `createDynamicURL` how do you set the `cardID` ?

Comment: It comes from a different part of my js file

Comment: Anyway, you can get the `card` in your view and use it in the template. Although, When you set `cardID` in a javascript, it means that you can have it in your template.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how exactly I should be using `cardID` in my template?

Comment: The way you are setting the `cardID` is not clear in your question.

Comment: If you are in `flash-detail` you have `cardID`. If you are in `flash-list` and looping over the cards you have `cardID`. if you are in `deck-list` or `deck-detail` and the `deck` has relationship with `flash` you have `cardID`

Comment: I've edited my question to include my study views and urls, since this is where I can get the card id. Could you please take another look?